# Awk one-liner to replace text of first matching regex occurence only

Tags: regex, awk, ksh, aix

I need this awk command to replace ss:Width="252" in the first XML tag in the text with ss:Width="140" and leave the rest of the tags alone:

```
cat <<- EOF > text
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="189"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="189"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
EOF

awk '{c=++count[$0]} c==1 {sub(/ss:Width=\"[0-9]{1,4}\"/,"ss:Width=\"140\"")} {print}' text > newf

cat newf
```

Instead, it replaces the expression in the first instances of each of the three unique matches (three total replacements, whereas I want only one.)

```
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="140"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="140"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="140"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="189"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
```

Why does it behave this way? How is the incrementer behaving in my awk command? I expected it to increment after the first qualifying match of /ss:Width=\".*\"/ but it seems like it's not incrementing until all *unique* matches are found, then ignoring subsequent non-unique matches only. Is that right? I tried to force the counter to increment at the end of the c == 1 block like this:

```
awk '{c=++count[$0]} c==1 {sub(/ss:Width=\".*\"/,"ss:Width=\"140\"");c++} {print}' text > newf
```

But I get the same output. I didn't have any luck trying this task in sed & I'd rather do it in awk anyway. I'm specifically interested in understanding this awk syntax.

Edit: I tested this theory by changing one of the width attributes to another random number. It does also replace that one with 140. So, it is limiting to the first instance of all matching expressions, not the first matching expression itself.

Edit: As Cody pointed out my regex is greedy. I changed .* to be [0-9]{1,4} however the behavior is the same - it still replaces only the first instance of every unique match. I also changed one of the XML tags' width attributes to a 3rd unique number and updated the output to illustrate the behavior I'm trying to fix.

This is AIX/ksh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'found == 0 { found = sub(/ss:Width=\"[0-9]{1,4}\"/,"ss:Width=\"140\"")} //' text > newf
```

You might be able to shorten that a bit.

Your old approach was keeping an array of counters indexed by the line of input. That's why it was exhibiting the behavior you weren't expecting.

Some of the other answers assume that all lines will match the `/ss:Width/` regex and/or always find the width attribute at the end of a line. It's probably true in your case but worthy of noting. I decided not to assume those things in the script above.

Comment: Thanks - that explanation is what I suspected but this solution doesn't work for me, I get this & haven't been able to fix it yet. Tried adding in an ending bracket in various places and no luck. "The error context is // {line=$0} found == 0 >>>  {line={ <<< awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed. The source line is 1. awk: There is a missing } character."

Comment: I'm trying to break down your syntax and understand it, I think this will help a lot. Also, I need it to match [0-9]{1,4}, not just 252 (it might not always be 252 in the first XML tag.)

Comment: Can you just do the substitution only when NR == 1? I think I'm not really sure which lines you want to be impacted.

Comment: I edited my answer to match on any numeric value in the width attribute. I think that might have been the problem.

Comment: Shawn, you are right that not all lines will contain ss:Width and I believe that's why NR == 1 won't work. This is just an excerpt from a larger XML document where I need to identify this block of text and transform the first of this series of tags. I got your command to execute, but now - I'm not sure why - it only prints "1" instead of the full XML tag on the first match.

1
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
<ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>

Etc. I tried found = $1 but I don't get that piece of it and it didn't work. Thanks, this is getting me closer!

Comment: I looked up the behavior of GNU `sub()`. If you version returns the number of matches and applies the substitution to $0 without a third argument then this should work. I thought the return value was string value so that should be why you were getting a "1".

Comment: This works perfectly. I tested it in a few different scenarios and the behavior is exactly what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your regular expression is greedy.

sub(regexp, replacement [, target])
    The sub function alters the value of target. It searches this value, which is treated as a string, for the **leftmost, longest substring matched by the regular expression regexp.**

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered that. But... I think because awk is line-oriented, it isn't evaluating the content of the other lines & eating up the full block of text. But you're right, I shouldn't be using .* - I replaced it with [0-9]{1,4} but I still get the same behavior unfortunately. Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk '($0 ~ /ss:Width/) {if (once != 1) {sub("[0-9]+\"/>","140\"/>")}; once=1; print}' text
```

It looks for the first line containing `ss:Width` then replaces the last number before the closing tag with `140`.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually pretty easy with custom field separators:

```
awk -F ' ss:Width="252"' -v r=' ss:Width="140"' '!p && NF>1{p=1; $1 = $1 r} 1' text
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="140"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="189"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="189"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="126"/>
    <ss:Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="252"/>
```

`-F ' ss:Width="252"'` sets field separator as the `ss:Width="252"`.

`!p && NF>1` puts replaced value `r` for the first instance of searched text.